# how to make nth-child include a range (eg. 0-19)

Tags: css

I have a bit of css code and each div child needs to have a property.

Hence it looks like this. It goes from 0 all the way to 19.

```
div:nth-child(0) { transform: translate3D(0%, 0%, calc(var(--itemZ) * var(--cameraSpeed) * 0 * -1px)); }
div:nth-child(1) { transform: translate3D(0%, 0%, calc(var(--itemZ) * var(--cameraSpeed) * 1 * -1px)); }
div:nth-child(2) { transform: translate3D(0%, 0%, calc(var(--itemZ) * var(--cameraSpeed) * 2 * -1px)); }
[...]
div:nth-child(17) { transform: translate3D(0%, 0%, calc(var(--itemZ) * var(--cameraSpeed) * 17 * -1px)); }
div:nth-child(18) { transform: translate3D(0%, 0%, calc(var(--itemZ) * var(--cameraSpeed) * 18 * -1px)); }
div:nth-child(19) { transform: translate3D(0%, 0%, calc(var(--itemZ) * var(--cameraSpeed) * 19 * -1px)); }
```

Is there a way that I can make it so it understands 0-19 in one line only?

Any ideas?

Comment: consider the use of SASS/LESS

Comment: No...there is not. This would be a *function* and CSS doesn't actually have those.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already use CSS variables, you can change the number to a variable (`--counter`), and set it on the div element. Now you can have a single line for all divs.

Example (I've simplified the CSS):

```css
:root {
  --cameraSpeed: 3;
  --itemZ: 2;
}

div {
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--counter, 0) * 10px));
}
```

```html
<div style="--counter: 0;">0</div>

<div style="--counter: 10;">10</div>

<div style="--counter: 19;">19</div>
```